# Convert Date with +1000 values

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have a date like this : 2018-04-30T23:22:05+1000 and want to convert in to `Date` Object

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:Z" // z, zz also still nil
let ss = formatter.date(from: "2018-04-30T23:22:05+1000")
print("VAL : \(ss)") // nil always
```

What is the correct format for +1000 values?

Also what locale i have to add to get exact date?

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` might be a better start

Comment: Just remove the colon between "ss" and "Z"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use your dateformat as [zone](https://waracle.com/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/) - The long specific non-location format. Where that is unavailable, falls back to the long localized GMT format (“0000”).

```
                             //2018-04-30T23:22:05+1000
       formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

instead of

```
       formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:Z" // z, zz also still nil
```

**full answer**

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" 
    let ss = formatter.date(from: "2018-04-30T23:22:05+1000")
    print("VAL : \(ss)") // nil always
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The date is an ISO 8601 date (Internet format) and the +1000 means +10 hours and 0 minutes (+hhmm). Parse it like this

```
let str = "2018-04-30T23:22:05+1000"
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()

formatter.formatOptions = .withInternetDateTime

let date = formatter.date(from: str)
```