# How to convert a String of certain format to Date in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I have strings like this `2020-09-21T21:13:55.636Z`... I want to convert them into `Date`s and here's what I do;

```
func convertToDate(str: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

    return dateFormatter.date(from: str)!
}
```

The above code crashes on the unwrapping. I'm guessing it's because of the format... Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Include the milliseconds in the format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I love you! Post it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Be aware that your app will crash if `str` can't be converted to a date

Comment: Here is an old answer from @JoakimDanielson [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50809888/13426627)

Comment: Note that this will create a new dateFormatter every time you call this property and it might fail if the user device 24hour is set to 12. You need to set the locale to "en_US_POSIX" before setting the dateFormat when parsing a fixed date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that date string you should use `ISO8601DateFormatter`, like this:

```
var str = "2020-09-21T21:13:55.636Z"

let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
let date = formatter.date(from: str)
```

That will save you the trouble of trying to get a format string exactly right.

Comment: This is wrong. You need to use `.withInternetDateTime` as well as `.withFractionalSeconds`. This would result in `"Dec 31, 1999 at 10:00 PM"`  `[.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]` or simply insert the fractional seconds to the default options `formatter.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Fixed, thank you